# Added 5 pens and 3 pencils. The ratio of pens to pencils is 47 to 17. What is bigger 1/3 or old ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You added 5 pens and 3 pencils in the drawer. Now ratio of pens to pencils is 47 to 17. What is bigger 1/3 or the ratio of pens to pencils before the addition?

The answer is : cannot be determined.

I wonder WHY.

GRE practice exam just says plug in values 47 and 17, and 2*47 and 2*17 and see that it gives different ratios. BUT, I need to understand intuition behind. Please explain me why such things could not be determined without "plug in numbers".

Thanks

Comment: The ratio of pens to pencils is certainly bigger than 1/3. The ratio of pencils to pens, however, is indeterminate relative to 1/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you start with $a$ pens and $b$ pencils. After you add $5$ pens and $3$ pencils you have $a+5$ pens and $b+3$ pencils. We’re told that

$$\frac{a+5}{b+3}=\frac{47}{17}\;,$$

which means that there is some integer $n$ such that $a+5=47n$ and $b+3=17n$. Moreover, $n$ can be *any* positive integer, so for each positive integer $n$ we get a possible pair $\langle a,b\rangle$ by setting

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
a&=47n-5\\
b&=17n-3\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

The original ratio is then

$$\frac{a}b=\frac{47n-5}{17n-3}=\frac{47}{17}+\frac{56}{17(17n-3)}\;,\tag{1}$$

since

$$47n-5=\frac{47}{17}(17n-3)+\frac{56}{17}\;.$$

Now $\frac{56}{17(17n-3)}$ can be made as small as we like by taking $n$ big enough, so the ratio in $(1)$, while always larger than $\frac{47}{17}$, can be made as close to $\frac{47}{17}$ as we like. The largest it can be is

$$\frac{47}{17}+\frac{56}{17\cdot14}=\frac{47}{17}+\frac4{17}=\frac{51}{17}=3\;,$$

when $n=1$. Thus, the ratio of pens to pencils is greater than $\frac{47}{17}$ and at most $3$. This is certainly greater than $\frac13$, but the ratio of pencils to pens is at least $\frac13$ but less than $\frac{17}{47}\approx0.3617$. That is, the ratio of pencils to pens can be $\frac13$, but it can also be greater than $\frac13$.